# Using CLOB instead of VARCHAR2

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, clob, varchar2

We want to create an XML. The current code does it by appending one XML tag at a time to a `VARCHAR2` variable.

```
xmlString                   VARCHAR2(32767);
....
....
xmlString := xmlString || '<' || elementName || '>' || elementValue || '</' || elementName || '>';
```

However due to size limitation of 32767 characters on `VARCHAR2`, we get the following error for a very long XML.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

The solution we have is to declare a `CLOB` and write a procedure to keep flushing the `VARCHAR2` variable to the `CLOB`.

```
v_result                    clob;
.....
.....
IF xmlString IS NOT NULL THEN
        dbms_lob.writeappend( v_result, LENGTH(xmlString), xmlString);
        xmlString := NULL;
END IF;
```

However this would require replacing lots of exiting code lines with calls to the new function. Is there a better way to do this?

Anything similar to Operator Overloading in PLSQL? Can I change the data type of `xmlString` variable to CLOB and make the `||` operator to do the work of `dbms_lob.writeappend`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you change the data type of `xmlString` to `clob`, the string concatenation operator will continue to work.

However, building XML this way would be a very poor architecture.  That's the sort of architecture that has a high probability of generating invalid XML when, for example, one of the strings happens to have a character that needs to be escaped (or for any of a number of different reasons).  Oracle provides a whole host of functions to generate XML ([XMLElement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm), [XMLForest](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions221.htm), [SYS_XMLGen](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions171.htm#i1004367), [DBMS_XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlque.htm#ARPLS376), etc. depending on your use case).  It would be far better architecturally to use those built-in functions.